# What can I do when my SSH session is stuck?

Tags: ssh

Sometimes my ssh session in the terminal hangs. How can I exit the ssh session and reconnect?

Comment: Same question on [UNIX&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2919/296692) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28981112/5267751).

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Type `~.` (i.e. tilde, period) at the beginning of a line. In other words, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>~</kbd>, then <kbd>.</kbd>. (In some languages, you may need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>⌥ Option/Alt</kbd> to enter the `~` character.)

Generally speaking, the `~` character is an escape character in an SSH session when you type it at the beginning of a line. Type <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `~?` to see the list of escape commands. The most common ones are

- `~.` to terminate the connection
- `~^Z` (press <kbd>~</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) to suspend the connection and type a command locally (run the command `fg` to return to the SSH session)

If you want a tilde at the beginning of a line, press <kbd>~</kbd> twice.

Comment: This works only if you have an ANSI keyboard, I have spanish keyboard and doens't work, in spanish the "tilde" key ~ is made with AltGr + 4. 
But if I change the keyboard layout to english, and I use Shift + º, then it works!

Comment: @JohanAlexisDuqueCadena I don't know what an “ANSI keyboard” is but I don't think it's relevant. If your tilde key is a dead key (i.e. typing `~` doesn't insert `~` immediately, but typing e.g. `~` then `a` inserts `ã`), you may need to type a space after `~` to actually insert a tilde, then type the second character. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219603/how-do-i-type-a-tilde-in-spanish-keyboard

Comment: Works for me with German keyboard layout and `Alt Gr + +`.

Comment: This worked for me in iTerm2 on MacOS. On my US keyboard, I had to type Shift + "~", then ".". I regret taking so many years to look for this answer.

Answer (score 11):

If your session is hung and the prompt is no longer responsive you can just kill the Terminal instance. All child processes associated with that instance, including your ssh session, exit.

A more thorough approach, open a new shell (new tab or window), list ssh sessions and send kill signals:

```
> ps -ef  |grep ssh
501  1332   142   0 20Dec11 ??         0:01.33 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
501 57172 57150   0  1:58pm ttys000    0:00.01 grep ssh
501 57139 57133   0  1:57pm ttys002    0:00.03 ssh -i/Users/ian/code/ec2-keys/id_rsa-gsg-keypair someuser@someinstance.amazonaws.com

> kill 57139
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
> kill -9 57139
```

Don't kill the `ssh-agent` or `sshd` Processes.

Or you can open Activity Monitor and search there for sessions and hit the "Quit Process" button for them:

[image: Activity Monitor filtering for ssh sessions]

Comment: +1, this is what I do. Often where I've left a session running, and then either the connection breaks accidentally or I sleep the laptop, it causes ssh to freeze. I open a new console tab and kill the PID of the ssh process (or close the ssh tab and open a new one)

Comment: Does using the keyboard shortcut work on your Mac without tediously killing the process?

Comment: Use `~.`. See above.

Answer (score 9):

<del>All you need to do to exit an ssh session is type `exit` at the prompt.</del>

Try entering <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: It's not accepting user input anymore, it's literally stalled. On Ubuntu there's a keyboard combination that terminates the session that you can use in cases like these. After a while the session will terminate stating `broken-pipe` but I rather not wait.

Comment: @Kit I fixed my answer. Sorry about that. I didn't realize you meant a completely stalled SSH session.

Comment: I usually just wait for it to timeout. Despite the fact that I know about these commands, I always forget that I can use them to expedite the process of getting my shell back.

Note @Gilles answer as well, you may have to press Enter/Return once before `~.`

You can learn more in the [SSH manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ssh.1.html) (a bit over halfway in), and by typing: `~?` into an active/connected SSH session, again, you may have to hit enter once before.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation:

```
 Supported escape sequences:
 ~.   - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
 ~B   - send a BREAK to the remote system
 ~C   - open a command line
 ~R   - request rekey
 ~V/v - decrease/increase verbosity (LogLevel)
 ~^Z  - suspend ssh
 ~#   - list forwarded connections
 ~&   - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
 ~?   - this message
 ~~   - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

Comment: It's from command `~?`, just copy-paste

Answer (score 1):

~. works, although it looks like being totally stuck, stops the ssh connection and you can start it again, but in my keyboard I have to press Alt+~ then space and then .

Answer (score 0):

For me, working with Terminal in macOS Mojave 10.14.6 the only solution was to enter ~ followed by Ctrl-Z as described in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175670/136875

Answer (score 0):

From Ian's answer on apple.stackexhange, this is the answer **for Mac OS X**:

> The default escape key for the ssh that ships with OS X the `~` character. You have to enter it immediately after a new line for ssh to respect it. And then the key sequence <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> is used to suspend and background a task in bash.

So try this key sequence:

<kbd>Return</kbd>

<kbd>~</kbd>

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

If it works you'll see something like:

```
myhost.local:~ |ruby-2.2.0|
> ssh someremotehost
Last login: Fri Mar  6 14:15:28 2015 from myhost

someremotehost:~ |ruby-2.2.0|
> ~^Z [suspend ssh]

[1]  + 48895 suspended  ssh myremotehost
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac users (new macs).

it's
`option` + `N`
then
`shift` + `; .`