# How to unfreeze terminal when SSH connection dies?

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh, internet

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 with bash shell. Occasionally when I ssh into another machine and then the connection dies (e.g. the Internet goes down or I move to a new location), the terminal window with the open SSH session is frozen and the only way I seem to be able to move ahead is to close it and start a new session.

Is there some way to configure things such that if the SSH session's connection dies, I will be returned back to my normal bash shell, as it was before I executed my `ssh` command?

Comment: Try configuring ServerAliveCountMax and ServerAliveInterval in your ~/.ssh/ssh_config.

Comment: @ScottDudley can you provide more details?

Comment: @phatmann eg. with `ServerAliveCountMax 4` and `ServerAliveInterval 15`, if the SSH client does not receive a response from the server after 4*15=60 seconds, it should disconnect automatically. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for more details.

Comment: `return` then `~.` more info https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35524/what-can-i-do-when-my-ssh-session-is-stuck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can suspend and then kill the `ssh` process that's hung up. To do this you have to issue the escape sequence, suspend the `ssh` process, and then use `kill -9` to kill that process.

The default escape key for the ssh that ships with OS X the `~` character. You have to enter it immediately after a new line for ssh to respect it. And then the key sequence <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> is used to suspend and background a task in bash.

So try this key sequence:

<kbd>Return</kbd>

<kbd>~</kbd>

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

If it works you'll see something like:

```
myhost.local:~ |ruby-2.2.0|
> ssh someremotehost
Last login: Fri Mar  6 14:15:28 2015 from myhost

someremotehost:~ |ruby-2.2.0|
> ~^Z [suspend ssh]

[1]  + 48895 suspended  ssh myremotehost
```

This line of output:

```
[1]  + 48895 suspended  ssh myremotehost
```

tell you the process ID of the `ssh` process on your machine. It's `48895` in this example. That process is still running, it's just been suspended and backgrounded. You need to kill it.

You can do that with the `kill` command. You want to kill it with prejudice so use the `-9` option when you call `kill` like so:

```
myhost.local:~ |ruby-2.2.0|
> kill -9 48895
[1]  + 48895 killed     ssh someremotehost
```

Just use the PID of *your* `ssh` process when you call that command in place of the `48895` PID I used above.

And you'll have your prompt back.

Alternatively, you can open a second Terminal window and use `ps` to find the `ssh` process in the process list and issue the `kill -9` call against the PID. Though, that kind of defeats the process of getting your prompt back in the original Terminal window, doesn't it?