# How do I type a tilde in spanish keyboard?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, internationalization

It is difficult work with the Terminal if you can't type the tilde. Does anybody know how to do this using a Spanish keyboard?

Comment: I remember keeping a text file around so I could copy paste the tilde on old unix workstations. Was a real hassle and luckily OS X has better support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a Spanish keyboard and Spanish keybindings the tilde is <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>ñ</kbd>. Using English keybindings (System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources) and a Spanish keyboard it's still <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>.
If you immediately enter a <kbd>/</kbd> afterwards, you don't need an extra space.

Note: On some keyboards the two <kbd>alt</kbd> keys are different. To get the tilde, you may have to use the <kbd>alt gr</kbd> key located to the right of the spacebar.

Answer (score -2):

On my Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux with Spanish keyboard layout it is <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>.

On Windows you will have to press <kbd>space</kbd> to only get the ~. Or something else that cannot be combined with the ~ like for example ã.

On my Linux I directly get the ~ character, but that behaviour is configurable.

I know it's the apple section. But I found this answer with Google searching for Windows and Linux. So I think my answer might be helpful.

Comment: No macos does it differently